# iCloud: disable incremental backup on file

Tags: ios, icloud

In the documents directory of my app is a big binary file that needs to be in the backup (isExcludedFromBackup = false). This works fine, but as iCloud does an incremental backup and my big binary file can change a lot, I'd like to disable the incremental backup on this file (otherwise the backup size will grow too fast).

Does somebody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try as follows:

do {

```
var url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "")
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
try url.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```

} catch {

}